# Why would Twitter have deprecated the use of DELETE as a request method in their API?

Tags: api, twitter, httprequest

Twitter has deprecated the use of all methods that use DELETE as a request method,

```
DELETE :user/lists/:id
```

And now instead uses POST as the request method,

```
POST lists/destroy
```

Why has Twitter have stopped using DELETE in their API altogether, and now only use POST and GET for all methods?

- Is it performance?
- Is it security?
- What are the advantages of
  building an API that only uses POST and GET?

Comment: vague guess: post/get are the bedrock of the web and most likely to get through content-aware firewalls, while delete may not.

Comment: @MarcB while it does make sense, it defeats the whole point of RESTful API design, which uses the several 'other' HTTP methods (DELETE, PUT, HEAD, etc) as part of the API 'protocol'.

Comment: @JamesBeith I noticed you reverted an edit to your question, just to include a signature. Signatures are discouraged, both edits that removed it are valid, please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures). You can add your twitter handle on your profile page, if you wish.

Comment: You've already asked on the [Twitter Dev list](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4993) (where people would know the answer to this question). I'm not sure you'll get anything but speculation here unless a dev chimes in here instead.

Comment: Salutions, signatures and taglines are no welcome on the Stack Exchange network, please refrain from using them. Please see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/419 . Thanks.

Comment: @user7116, although you had the right in 2012, it was an excellent decision to repeat the question here. In 2022 the mentioned discussion link goes to null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there were compatibility issues with some clients being able to issue `DELETE` requests.  Looking back at the [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/delete/:user/lists/:id) for one of the deprecated calls, I found this blurb.

> **Usage Note:** clients who can not issue `DELETE` requests can `POST` with
>   the added parameter `_method=DELETE`

So, my feeling (and guess) is that since the `DELETE` verb wasn't uniformly supported, it was removed system-wide.

---

**Update:** I sent a tweet to Taylor ([@episod](https://twitter.com/#!/episod)) at Twitter and asked what he thought about the above, and he sent the following responses:

> @arcain *[the answer]* pretty much covers it; no disrespect intended to idyllic REST.
>   DELETE still usually works on those methods, but we omit from docs. [[link](https://twitter.com/episod/status/213644274523312128)]
>
> @arcain though most of the methods mentioned there weren't deprecated
>   because of the HTTP method so much as because of clumsy URL patterns. [[link](https://twitter.com/episod/status/213644530753347584)]

So, usability -- along with compatibility -- seem to have been the key concerns with the deprecations.